# Filling NaN by 'ffill' and 'interpolate' depending on time of the day of NaN occurrence in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, series

I want to fill NaN in a df using 'mean' and 'interpolate' depending on at what time of the day the NaN occur. As you can see below, the first NaN occur at 6 am and the second NaN is at 8 am.

```
02/03/2016 05:00    8
02/03/2016 06:00    NaN
02/03/2016 07:00    1
02/03/2016 08:00    NaN
02/03/2016 09:00    3
```

My df consists of thousand of days. I want to apply 'ffill' for any NaN occur before 7 am and apply 'interpolate' for those occur after 7 am. My data is from 6 am to 6 pm.

My attempt is:

```
df_imputed = (df.between_time("00:00:00", "07:00:00", include_start=True, include_end=False)).ffill()
df_imputed = (df.between_time("07:00:00", "18:00:00", include_start=True, include_end=True)).interpolate()
```

But it cut my df down to the assigned time periods rather than filling the NaN as I want.

Edit: my df contains around 400 columns so the procedure will apply to all columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Original question: single series of values

You can define a Boolean series according to your condition, then [`interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) or [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ffill.html) as appropriate via [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
# setup
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['02/03/2016 05:00', '02/03/2016 06:00', '02/03/2016 07:00',
                            '02/03/2016 08:00', '02/03/2016 09:00'],
                   'value': [8, np.nan, 1, np.nan, 3]})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# construct Boolean switch series
switch = (df['date'] - df['date'].dt.normalize()) > pd.to_timedelta('07:00:00')

# use numpy.where to differentiate between two scenarios
df['value'] = np.where(switch, df['value'].interpolate(), df['value'].ffill())

print(df)

                 date  value
0 2016-02-03 05:00:00    8.0
1 2016-02-03 06:00:00    8.0
2 2016-02-03 07:00:00    1.0
3 2016-02-03 08:00:00    2.0
4 2016-02-03 09:00:00    3.0
```

---

#### Updated question: multiple series of values

With multiple value columns, you can adjust the above solution using [`pd.DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) and [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html). Or, instead of `iloc`, you can use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) or other means (e.g. [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html)) of selecting columns:

```
# setup
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['02/03/2016 05:00', '02/03/2016 06:00', '02/03/2016 07:00',
                            '02/03/2016 08:00', '02/03/2016 09:00'],
                   'value': [8, np.nan, 1, np.nan, 3],
                   'value2': [3, np.nan, 2, np.nan, 6]})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# construct Boolean switch series
switch = (df['date'] - df['date'].dt.normalize()) > pd.to_timedelta('07:00:00')

# use numpy.where to differentiate between two scenarios
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].interpolate().where(switch, df.iloc[:, 1:].ffill())

print(df)

                 date  value  value2
0 2016-02-03 05:00:00    8.0     3.0
1 2016-02-03 06:00:00    8.0     3.0
2 2016-02-03 07:00:00    1.0     2.0
3 2016-02-03 08:00:00    2.0     4.0
4 2016-02-03 09:00:00    3.0     6.0
```

Comment: thanks for your useful tips. I can use it for one column df. But, I  forgot to write that my df has many columns. Please see my edit.

Comment: How if column 'date' is set as index?

Comment: Use `df.index` or promote to a column via `df.reset_index()`.

Comment: sorry, but first it reject 'dt', then it gives `ValueError: Array conditional must be same shape as self`.

Comment: Can't reproduce, works fine for me. Looks like you are unable to manipulate your dataframe into the format I've defined. That's likely [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).