# Replacing NaN returns ValueError: Array conditional must be same shape as self

Tags: python

My aim is to impute error values (zeros and negatives) using 'ffill' (if they occur before 7 am) and 'interpolate' (for error >= 7 am). My 'text' file contains thousands of days and hundreds of columns. Below is a small part of it showing three days with errors both before and after 7 am.

```
date                 a    b    c        
2016-03-02 06:55:00  0.0  1.0  0.0
2016-03-02 07:00:00  2.0  2.0  0.0
2016-03-02 07:55:00  3.0  0.0  3.0
2016-03-03 06:10:00 -4.0  4.0  0.0
2016-03-03 07:00:00  5.0  5.0  5.0
2016-03-03 07:05:00  6.0  0.0  6.0
2016-03-03 08:05:00  7.0  0.0  7.0
2016-03-03 17:40:00  8.0  8.0 -8.0
2016-03-04 05:55:00  0.0  9.0  0.0
2016-03-04 06:00:00  0.0  0.0  10.0
```

A small varition of codes from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53697353/filling-nan-by-ffill-and-interpolate-depending-on-time-of-the-day-of-nan-occ/53697422?noredirect=1#comment94263076_53697422) below work perfectly with other df when 'date' is a column.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

# Change zeros and negatives to NaN
df.replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)  
df[df < 0] = np.nan                  

# construct Boolean switch series
switch = (df.index - df.index.normalize()) > pd.to_timedelta('07:00:00')

# use numpy.where to differentiate between two scenarios
df.iloc[:, 0:] = df.iloc[:, 0:].interpolate().where(switch, df.iloc[:, 0:].ffill())
```

But, when the 'date' is made index, the codes return `ValueError: Array conditional must be same shape as self`. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The following finally solved my problem.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
# don't set column 'date' to index

# Change zeros and negatives to NaN
df.replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)  
df[df.loc[:, df.columns != 'date'] < 0] = np.nan # change negatives to NaN,   
                                                 # but exclude column 'date',   
                                                 # otherwise, column 'date' will be   
                                                 # converted to NaT  

# construct Boolean switch series
switch = (df['date'] - df['date'].dt.normalize()) > pd.to_timedelta('07:00:00')

# use numpy.where to differentiate between two scenarios
df.iloc[:, 0:] = df.iloc[:, 0:].interpolate().where(switch, df.iloc[:, 0:].ffill())
```

Thanks @jpp for suggesting the most important last two lines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53697353/filling-nan-by-ffill-and-interpolate-depending-on-time-of-the-day-of-nan-occ/53697422?noredirect=1#comment94263076_53697422).